# Apply styles inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs

I use react js library for my application and i want to apply some styles depending by a state, like:

```js
  const chooseAnAnswer = () => {
  if (answer.length > 2) {
    document.querySelector('.selector.new').style.background = 'red';
  }
  }
```

The `chooseAnAnswer` is a function from a select component. Depending of what you select, it changes the state.
Now it works, but i want to change my code to:

```js
const chooseAnAnswer = () => {
  useEffect(()=> {
    if (answer.length > 2) {
    document.querySelector('.selector.new').style.background = 'red';
  }
  }, [var])
  }
```

... to keep the state updated.
The issue is that i can't use `useEffect()` inside a function.

How to wrap my condition in useEffect() hook?

Answer (score 1):

You should not manipulate the DOM when using React. You can use a state for the color and then rerender the component using this color:

```
const [color, setColor] = useState();

const chooseAnAnswer = () => {
  if (answer.length > 2) setColor('red');
}

<div style={{backgroundColor: color}} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is a hook that needs to be used at the top level of functional React component. see the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

```
    function MyCoolComponent() {
      const [color, setColor] = useState();
      useEffect(() => {
        if(answerLength > 2) { setColor('red') }
      }, [answerLength]);
  ......
```

Comment: how to wrap my condition in useEffect?